# What logic function does this layout implement?

Tags: cmos, layout

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the following layout. I can't understand what logic function it is implementing.

[image]

For what I understand the rightmost side implements a CMOS inverter with input "a". The leftmost one is also a CMOS inverter with input y1 and output y2. Finally at the middle we have a NMOS and PMOS with both gates connected to "b", source connected to "~a" (is it though? the NMOS is missing a contact), and drain  connected to y1. I can't understand what logic function it implements. Can someone help me?

EDIT: My attempt on schematics
[image]

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: @jsotola I'm self studying layout.

Comment: Could you please redraw the schematic in a more "traditional" software, so we can understand your question better? I have no clue what these colored rectangles stand for.

Comment: @uriyaba thank you for your response. The layout isn't mine but I can provide a small label. Red rectangles are poly, blue rectangles are metal (VDD at the top, GND at the bottom), small black rectangles are black, green rectangles at the bottom part are n diffusion, green rectangle at the top is n-well, brown rectangles are p diffusion. Is it clearer now?

Comment: It still isn't very clear to me, sorry. If you would represent the schematic as a clear electronic circuit (for example, replace the rectangles with the corresponding MOSFETs and wire them up properly), I would most likely be able to help you.

Comment: I'm exactly having trouble doing that but I will try and upload a new pic in a minutes, of my attempt on doing the schematics. Just give me 10 minutes!

Comment: @uriyaba schematics  done!

Comment: Can you tell us where you found this layout? Surely the source provides some explanation for what this is to represent. It seems strange that you would find some random bit of layout with no other information.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson it was just on the layout examples of a portuguese book that I'm following

Comment: @GrangerObliviate What is the name of the book and who is the author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only parameter we're missing in order to find the boolean function this circuit implements is y1, let us look at the CMOS in the rightmost diagram that you have drawn, since it is a fair simplification of the circuit.

Suppose that a = '0'; The PMOS will enter the cutoff region, since its Vsg will be less than |Vt|, no matter what b's logical value is equal to. However, the NMOS will always be at either the saturation region (when b = '0') or the linear region (when b = '1'), so in this case where a = '0', the PMOS will be cutoff, and the NMOS will conduct, such as that its drain voltage will be equal to its source voltage (a, in this case, which is again, equal to 0). An example circuit for one of the mentioned cases:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8wWpd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1: a = '0' and b = '0'. Simulation shows y1='0'.*

Now that you (hopefully) understood what I've explained so far, ask yourself these questions - what happens to the MOSFETs in the other cases, where a='1'? What will y1 logical value be equal to in these cases? And finally, after arriving at some conclusions, it will be possible to construct a truth table in order to find y1, which in turn would help you find y2.

Oh, and you could also simulate the circuit if you get stuck, and then try to explain to yourself why the simulation shows that specific value for y1 :)

Comment: Thank you very much, it definitely helped, specially the simulation! when a=1 the PMOS always conducts and my guess is that the NMOS might conduct or not (b=0, does not conduct, b=1 conducts), and the output y1=1. We shall conclude the logic function is y1=a and y2=~a. Is that correct? So overall this is a NOT gate. I wonder why the inclusion of input b. Is it just to implement a transmission gate with these two transistors and has no practical meaning?

Comment: I'm glad to have helped! I'd appreciate it if you accepted my answer and upvoted it, since this is common practice around here when an answer is helpful. As for your conclusions, you almost got it right - you're only wrong about one thing, when a = '1' the NMOS **never** conducts;  it's in its cutoff region since its Vgs < |Vt|, no matter what b's logical value is.

Comment: I will do so! Oh you are right because since y1 is 1 the source always has a voltage bigger or equal than the gate, therefore the NMOS won't conduct! Thank you again!